# How to composite multiple API call in API gateway?

Tags: api-design, api-gateway

I am looking in to how to use API gateway in my project. My current API gateway pattern idea is to create a layer of composite APIs calling multiple APIs, and expose the composite APIs through the API gateway.

Researching elsewhere, I've found that it is not recommended to create composite APIs if using an API gateway, but rather that composition should happen in the API gateway itself. But if I need to do the composition in API gateway, doesn't that mean that I need to expose some domain logic there, because would I need to construct a meaningful request contract and possibly a sequence of calling APIs? Personally, I don't feel comfortable doing that.

Is there other way to do this without exposing some logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I research, it is not recommended to create composite API if using API gateway but composition should happen in the API gateway itself.

could you refer where did you find the statement?

IMHO the service composition is not task of the api gateway.  It's task of n integration layer (you don't need to have a separate esb product or service, under integration lyer  you can understand any services or service layer implementing the capabilities, such as composition, transformation, etc)

You did not specify any api product or service, it depends on the product if it is capable to execute any logic or not (some do, some some don't). Even if the api gateway product is capable of executing any logic, indeed I don't recommend it either (you will have to fight with maintenance, error and state handling,..)

> But if I need to do the composition in API gateway, doesn't it means that I need to expose some domain logic there 
>   (personally, I don't feel comfortable doing that) because I need to construct a meaningful request contract and possibly sequence of calling APIs?

what do you mean by `composition in API gateway`? I assume under the term executing some logic. Then the logic is hidden from the api clients.

> Or could it be layer of composite API sounds better?

Indeed.

Generally try to treat an api gateway as a smart proxy (doing authorization, throttling, client facing api store,..) but the exposed backend services should be already exposed as they are

Comment: I read from some blog but couldn't remember which was it, and some API guy from my company told me that as well. The reasons I get was because:  
1. One extra component (composite APIs) to maintain, 
2. Duplicate functionality in service (because composite APIs have all those underlying services functions)

Comment: Is it good practice to do api response composition at api gateways ?